# Finishing activity after changing the orientation , transition not smooth

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have 2 `activities A and B`. `Activity A in in portrait view` and then i call Activity B. Then I change the orientation if the device , then `Activity B is in landscape view`. When i finish activity B, I see the Activity A in landscape view, but the transition of finishing activity is not smooth. I see a glitch while transition occurs.

I have used

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
```

in the `AndroidManifest` for both the activity.

`How can i make the transition smooth?` Can any one pls help?